# How to use DFT to solve 1D wave equation numerically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, wave-equation

The wave equation

$$ u_{tt} = u_{xx} $$

with conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$, and $u_{t}(x,0)=0$, has following solution in frequency spectrum,

$$ \hat{u} = \hat{f} \cos(\omega t) $$

and I tried to solve numerically in Python by inverting this in every time step.

The `numpy.fft(f)` only results in the amplitude of the frequencies, and it does not specify which amplitude is for which frequency. But some reference say the $\omega=0, 1/(n \triangle t), ...$ where $n$ is the number of points to evaluate $f(x)$.
But the result looks weird. Do I miss something here?

Comment: Hi @Snoop , here is the PDE question.